# Action when modal closes in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I am using Modal component from vue strap. I want to know if an action/method can be run if modalshow is false. Basically I want to do a status check and then refresh the page when the modal closes.

Comment: You should post some code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use watch in parent component:

```
watch: {
  'showModal': function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if(newVal == false)
      doSomething();
  }
},
```

when modal show status changes this event should fire up.
Remember to use twoWay binding in modal component for showModal:

```
<modal large :show.sync="showModal" effect="zoom">
```